# How do I best-determine system requirements for a new app?

Tags: c#, windows, performance, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to specify the hardware your software needs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170939/how-to-specify-the-hardware-your-software-needs)

How do you determine the system requirements of a user's PC in order for them to install and run your software?

I am aware of the obvious, such as Windows, .NET Framework [version number]. But how do you come up with the correct RAM, Processor and all of that?

Is this just something that you observe while you're debugging your app? Do you just check out the Resource Monitor and watch for how much Disk usage your app is using, or how much memory it is taking up?

Are there any tools, or would you recommend I use tools to help determine system requirements for my applications?

I've searched for this but I have not been able to find much information.

*More importantly, what about the Windows Experience Index? I've seen a few box apps in the shop say you need a Windows Exp. Index of N, but are there tools that determine what index is required for my app to run?*

Comment: Thanks for the link @DanielA.White - I didn't see that in the results.

Answer (score 2):

Until you start doing stress testing and load testing, using or carefully simulating production volumes and diversity of data, you do not really have a high quality build ready for mass deployment.

And when you do, experience (measurements and, if necessary, projection) from this testing will give you RAM, CPU and similar requirements for your customers.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the resource monitor is a good way to see how much CPU and ram it consumes. But it all depends on the app you're making, and as the developer you know aprox. how much power is needed under the hood.

If you're just developing standard WinForms / VCL apps that use standard native controls, you really shouldn't worry too much - 256 MB RAM and a 1 GHz processor should be enough, this is usually what I tend to put on my sysreq page.

For heavy 3D games you should probably start looking more into it, how you do that I can't tell you.

If you REALLY want exact hertz and bytes, you could use a VM and alter the specs and see how your app behaves.